# Local caching with Parse

Tags: android, caching, parse-platform

I'm facing a pretty big problem today: I decided to use Parse as a backend for my mobile application. When retrieving data from server, Parse put the result in a local cache so we can use it offline too, which is great. But when adding or updating an object offline, Parse has no mechanism to update the local cache, which leads to big problems when the app has to be used offline.

I decided to maintain a local cache by myself using SQLite : I look on the server entries and on the local cache entries and then, using the dates, I manage to synchronize the data. The problem is that the updatedAt and createdAt fields are set when data are saved in the backend (which is normal), but then how do I know that an entry created offline is older or younger that the online data ? I could use the phone's time but that's quite random knowing that there could be a difference of some minutes.

Any idea?
I'm even open about new tools to use. I mean I'm not focused on Parse so if you have the perfect tool just tell me!

Answer (score 0):

you could set a `last synced time` in shared preferences and if the updated or created time is > the last sync time then you know it is new then update the last sync time again when your sync is done

Answer (score 0):

How about `saveEventually()`? Based on the explanation in the [API docs](http://www.parse.com/docs/android/api/), I think this will solve the problem.

Also, one more suggestion, if you want to cache your ParseObject, instead of the painful SQLite and tables and all, you could use internal storage to save the object as is explained in this [article](http://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2013/04/07/caching-objects-in-android-internal-storage/).

Comment: saveEventually() does not store the data in the cache neither. So you cannot access it offline until the data has been sent to the server. Moreover, saveEventually() remember that it should save the data for an undefined time (I read it somewhere but I do not remember).

Comment: Anyway, saving the object on the internal storage may be a better way than SQLite. ParseObject neither implements the Serializable interface nor the Parcellable interface so my I should update my POJOs to store a reference to my objects so I can save it.
I'll think about the best way to do it. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah...you cannot access the data offline until it the data has been sent to the server. Probably, you could store the data to the internal storage simultaneously and use this storage to populate the views.

Comment: I'm currently changing my POJOs so they do not subclass ParseObject anymore and I'll try internal storage.
I'll tell you the result when I'm finish

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem on Class with pointer.
Known bug: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/parse-developers/arRBB7S559M